# Menu icons not showing in Liferay 7

Tags: navigation, liferay, liferay-7

I have created a theme for Liferay 7 GA4 and I want to show menu icons on my naviagation menu.
I have added the icons and I have inserted the code in my ftl template file, but they are not showing.

My code:

```
<a href="${nav_child.getURL()}" ${nav_child.getTarget()}>
<#if nav_child.iconURL()??><img src="${nav_child.iconURL()}" title="${nav_child.getTitle()}" /></#if> ${nav_child.getName()}
</a>
```

The html produced is the following:

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/web/demo-site/mypage"> <img src="/image/layout_icon?img_id81132&amp;t=1505989275032" title=""> My page</a>
```

But the icon does not appear. Also in the chrome dev console the image appears as empty / transparent.

Are there any other settings that I have to configure in order to show the icons?

Edit:
Browser's console shows that the images do not exist 404 (Not Found).
*Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) layout_icon*

Thanks in advance.

Yannis

Edit:

In navigation menu on the left I click on "configure page"

[image]

And then I add an icon

[image]

This icon is not displayed on my page.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found what was the problem.

It is probably a **bug** as when I print ${nav_child.iconURL()} there is a "=" missing from the url.

faulty url: "/image/layout_icon?img_id81132&t=1506598606029"

correct url: "/image/layout_icon?img_id=81132&t=1506598606029"

With a replace i managed to print the icons:

```
${nav_child.iconURL()?replace("img_id", "img_id=")}
```

works...

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in your template you have added an image field and uploaded that image. The way you can get it to display is by using `.getData()` with the name of the image field.

For example: `<img src="${image.getData()}" />` where `image` is the name of your field.

Comment: I added a few photos to understand where exactly is the issue. It is not a custom field created by me. It is the buit in feature of adding icons.